# How to aggregate after applying FeatureHasher() in PyPsark?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, feature-engineering

I am using FeatureHasher() on my categorical columns of my training dataset:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, Window
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector, DenseVector
from pyspark.ml.feature import FeatureHasher

cateogrical_cols = ["SupplyVendor",
                    "Country",
                    "Region",
                    "Metro",
                    "City"]
hasher = FeatureHasher(inputCols=cateogrical_cols, outputCol="hashed_features")
hashed_df = hasher.transform(train_df)
```

The result of the FeatureHasher looks like this:

```
Schema:
ID: String
hashed_features: udt

ID hashed_features
1  {"vectorType": "sparse", "length": 262144, "indices": [35280, 47124, 129786, 131057, 132362, 154002, 164520, 178389, 193783, 232152], "values": [1, 1, 4, 113, 1, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1]}
2  {"vectorType": "sparse", "length": 262144, "indices": [55659, 82764, 122047, 129786, 131057, 154002, 164520, 179105, 180969, 193783, 203119], "values": [1, 1, 1, 2, 106, 6, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1]}
2  {"vectorType": "sparse", "length": 262144, "indices": [129786, 131057, 154002, 164054, 164520, 167213, 186856, 193783, 201824, 226821], "values": [4, 105, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]}
```

How can I apply aggregation grouping by ID, so I can have one `hashed_features` record a given ID that has all distinct `indices` and corresponding sum of `values`? I then would need to run this resultant through VectorAssembler() to do model training. But having trouble on this aggregation step.

I have tried many methods and nothing is working. It is difficult to extract the `indices` and `values` from a column of type `udt`. Any help is appreciated!

Here's one attempt:

```
# Aggregate the hashed_features by ID and collect distinct indices and values
aggregated_df = df.groupBy('ID').agg(
    collect_set(expr('hashed_features.indices')).alias('distinct_indices'),
    collect_set(expr('hashed_features.values')).alias('distinct_values')
)

# Sort the arrays of indices and values
sorted_df = aggregated_df.withColumn('distinct_indices', sort_array('distinct_indices')) \
    .withColumn('distinct_values', sort_array('distinct_values'))
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: [INVALID_EXTRACT_BASE_FIELD_TYPE] Can't extract a value from "hashed_features". Need a complex type [STRUCT, ARRAY, MAP] but got "STRUCT, values: ARRAY>".; line 1 pos 0
```